# how to use format specifier on string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use format specifier on numbers in string

```
Alist = ["1,25,56.7890,7.8"]

tokens = Alist[0].split(',')

for number in tokens:
    print "%6.2f" %number ,
```

Outcome: It gives me error.

Comment: In your example, just to write `print number` instead of `print "%6.2f" %number` would be the most obvious solution, but what is it, that you want to do in the end (I'm guessing you don't just want to print the numbers, or?)? And are you sure you need to format the strings to numbers to archieve your goal? If you are, int() for integers or float() for floats should work.

Comment: Try `print "%6.2f" % float(number)`

Comment: Or look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/python-limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Comment: You have a string, after splitting you have a list of strings; to treat those strings as numbers requires you to convert them to numbers *first*.

Answer (score 3):

`TypeError: float argument required, not str`

Your error clearly states that you are trying to pass a String off as a Float.

You must cast your string value to a float:

```
for number in tokens: 
    print '{:6.2f}'.format(float(number))
```

**Note** If you are using a version of python earlier than [2.6](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) you cannot use `format()`
You will have to use the following:

```
print '%6.2f' % (float(number),) # This is ugly.
```

Here is some documentation on [Python 2.7 format examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples).

Comment: Good catch. I must have copied my old for loop.

Comment: No worries.  I fixed up your old-style one as well (removed the period before `%`).

Comment: `format` is fine for Python 2.6 - You just can't omit the numbered parameters, so the above would have to be: `{0:6.2f}` as the format string for instance. I would also write the above as `format(float(number), '6.2f')` instead

Comment: Coming from a C background,  `format(value, format_spec)` looks strange to me.

Comment: If something looks ugly to me in the second piece, it's the explicit tuple notation.  When you say "earlier than 2.6", do you mean also that you can't do `'%6.2f' % float(number)`?  Or the reason for the comment is that you just don't like the `%` operator itself?